# What type of smart switch has neutral, up, down states?

Tags: switch, smart-switch, home-automation

I'm having motorised blinds installed and the vendor plans to install a wall switch to control them. The switch has three states: Middle, or the default and off position; up and down, which will roll the blind up and down respectively.

I would like to replace the stock switches with smart ones (the vendor won't do it) that can be controlled via a smart assistant.

I thought of [a "three-way" switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09T3CMVDP) (it makes sense since the stock switch has three states), but according to my research, those refer to switches that control a circuit from two locations (two switches controlling one light, for example).

Which type of switch would I need for my setup?

Comment: There are a variety of [IoT.se] blinds switches available. A simple internet search for "smart motorized blind switch" turned up all sorts of listings. Since we don't do shopping questions here, that's about the best we can give you. Besides, your smart switch will need to live within your existing (or planned) IoT environment, so you'll need to know which protocols it will need to support and you haven't even told us that.

Comment: Thanks, noted. I badly phrased my question. I did plenty of research but everything led me to the "three-state switch" and I thought there was a technical name for the switch I'm looking for that escaped me (not looking for fancy IoT either, just a connected off-the-shelf switch with three states). I'm also searching from a non-English speaking country, so Google shows me localised results which lack relevance sometimes.

Comment: I'm not really sure what a "connected" switch is if it doesn't fall into the broad category of IoT. That's where all the "smart" devices live, whether there's access to them from outside the house or not. (I put "smart" in quotes, because some of my devices are acting _very_ dumb at the moment...)

Comment: @FreeMan gotcha. Fair point. Here's an example: https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/552d2313e4b0906b45be9b82/1433774998514-7H8PG5GMEDXR2YN7TV2O/Persiana+ou+Veneziana+Externa+%281%29.jpg?format=1500w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three position switches, which is what you are thinking of.

There are also three position momentary rocker switches with a spring-return, which is what most blind controllers would use.  An example is here: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61QPAZUkbmS._SL1000_.jpg

But a momentary rocker switch is not a great thing to control with a voice command.
Most successful installations of these things have some way of determining when the blind is successfully opened or closed, which requires additional sensors and wiring.  So retrofitting a smart switch onto this application sounds like a recipe to burn out the motor or break the blinds.

Comment: Thanks! Great point re motor stop points. The electrical motor has those sensors installed since the factory switch (looks like a light switch but with three positions) would have the same issue anyway. When they install the motor they calibrate its stop points to cut off electricity to the switch. I should hope that a smart switch would work in the same way.